# Как сделать контент ровным у блока со свойством skew

Tags: html, css

[image: Пример]

Нужно сделать блок со свойством `transform: skew();` в котором картинка стоит ровно, пытаюсь так сделать но получается что картинка выходит за рамки самого блока. Пытался ставить ей свойство `position: absolute | position: relative | z-index -1` , и вставлял её как блок внутрь самого блока со свойством `skew`, и делал как элемент `::before` и элемент `::after` всё равно картинка выходит за края блока. В интернете показывают только как выровнять текст в таких блоках а про картинки ни слова.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Пример]

Чтобы изображение не выходило за рамки блока, нужно было в свойства блока прописать `overflow: hidden;`.